# Django how to send an email with the user link?

Tags: django, django-views, django-email

Hi i am newbie in Django just learning from the documentation.I just used django send an email https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/.
i want to send an email in join message want to send an a url with its driver ID in it for book a car . how do i send an url with his id . for example i am having 4 user in my employe site . our company employe hit the link send an email to the user which is registered . after click on send an email how do i get the driver id in my url and send him as in join message a link where his id in the url .

**Views.py**

```
def rentacar_carapp_approve(request):
    if request.POST:
        try:
            args['driver'] = driver = Driver.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('driver_id'))
            subject = "Please Register Your Car"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = driver_email
            if to_email is not None:
                join_message = """Please hit the link and book a car "url with his id " """
                send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[to_email], message=join_message,
                          fail_silently=False)
                print("email sent")
        except Driver.DoesNotExist:
            print("Driver doesn't exists")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/mega-admin/rentacar/carapp-manager/')
```

**Url.py**

```
url(r'^drivers/(?P<driver_id>\d+)/$',rent_views.book,name='book'),
```

Comment: Why not render it with the Django template engine?

Comment: how do i render it ?

Comment: Furthermore it might be better to give the path a `name`, and use *named* parameters. Right now it is unclear to me what the two `\d+`s are doing.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i changed my url path now . i just want to send an email to the driver with his id after click on the link . his id will in it

Comment: render() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem your answer is not showing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
if request.is_secure():
   protocol = 'https://'
else:
   protocol = 'http://'

host = request.get_host()

url = protocol + host + reverse('url_name', kwargs={user_id: user_id})
```

- kwargs may be null if there is no arguements with the url pattern.

Then concatenate the url with your message body in send email().